# I can't send emails - Firebase CloudFunctions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase Cloud Functions and I want to create a mailing system on it. I need to receive an email in my account (for example myemail@gmail.com) every time a new data is inserted in my Realtime Database.The email must contain the contents of the firebase node.

I tried to use this code, but when adding new data to the Realtime database, I don't get any emails:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email@gmail.com',
    pass: 'password'
  },
});

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendEmail = functions.database.ref('/reports/{postId}/{reportId}').onWrite(async (change) => {
  const snapshot = change.after;
  const val = snapshot.val();

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Report" <email@gmail.com>',
    to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  };

  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = 'Report ' + val.tipo;
  mailOptions.text = 'Content ' +  val;

  try {
    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('email sent! ');
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error);
  }
  return null;

});
```

Database:

```
  "reports" : {
    "-M2sV-8jze4u8di8rC6a" : {
      "-M2smZT3YgGe6pbHb9ML" : {
        "idAuthor" : "-M2sV-8jze4u8di8rC6a",
        "idReport" : "-M2smZT3YgGe6pbHb9ML",
        "tipo" : "test"
      },
```

How can I do to send emails with the contents of the database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail exactly what is not working the way you expect.  Are there errors?  Have you tried to debug anything?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Question updated

Comment: You might want to add some more `console.log` statements to the code, to make it easier to spot *what* isn't working. Is your function getting triggered? Does `val` contain the data you'd expect? Without you telling us those things, we'll likely only spot obvious things, and (2 hours after posting this) it seems that there are not a lot of things obviously wrong about what you posted.

Comment: may you please add a console.log at the very beginning of your function, to check if it even fires? Oh and by the way, if you want to send E-Mails to your users you may use Firestore, its cheaper and does the same job, Realtime Databases are designed for things like chat messages etc, the milliseconds really don't matter with your E-Mail reports.